# WPF: Binding to array using ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

When using `ItemsControl` to bind to a property of type `List<byte>`, I get the correct values in one direction (displayed using a `TextBox` with a hexadecimal `StringConverter`), but changing the value has no effect (i.e. the source is not updated). Binding mode is the default. Changing the property to be a `ObservableCollection` instead of a list has no effect. (The problem is independent of whether the `StringConverter` is used or not.)

The item template (working in the source-to-display direction) I'm using below.

```
            <ItemsControl
                ItemsSource="{Binding Context.ContentBytes}">

                <!-- Container configuration -->
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid Columns="8" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox
                            Margin="5,5,5,5"
                            Text="{Binding .}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

            </ItemsControl>
```

The property I'm binding to is defined as `public ObservableCollection<byte> ContentBytes { get; set; }` .

Comment: When you change the values in your textbox did you check if you ValueConverter is getting the right values that it is expecting?

Comment: Show us more code: the defintion of whatever `Context` is (if it's large, just show the definition and `ContentBytes` defined within) and tell us how you're updating `ContentBytes`.

Comment: Editing and thus *changing* the elements of a collection does not *replace* them in the collection. However, your changes get lost because the element type is a value type, not a reference type.